# Need help on easy topic

Tags: lm

Quick and easy question. I was wondering when we are doing a regression in R, what does it mean if we do this:

```
Y ~ .
```

Instead of let's say

```
Y ~ X
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

The dot signifies any columns from data that are otherwise not used. `y ~ x` means `y` is proportional to `x`, i.e.,  `y = mx + b`.

In other words, an expression `y ~ model` meanss that the response `y` is modeled by the linear predictor, `model`.

[See this article](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/formula.html) and [see this s.o. post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13446256/meaning-of-tilde-dot-argument)

Comment: If I understand correctly, Y ~ . will be Y ~ all other columns in my dataset except the the column for Y?