# Tilde Dot in R (~.)

Tags: r, dplyr

Can anyone explain the tilde dot (~.) in R? I have seen some posts about it already. I know the tilde is used for formulas, specifying the independent and dependent variables. And, I know that the dot is used to indicate all other variables. More specifically, can someone explain the tilde dot in this example?

```
x <- sample(10)
x %>%
  detect(~. > 5)
```

Thanks

Comment: might be worth some time to read R manual pages as noted in the answer. it's explained really clearly in there.

Comment: And it's important to know that tilde-dot isn't a compound operator or anything. They are two separate things. You could have also done `detect(~5 < .)`. They each are doing something different. You are making a formula (with `~`) that uses a special variable (named `.`) which some function interpret as a creating a lambda function (but this is true mostly just for "tidyverse" functions).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As MrFlick pointed out, these are two separate operators. Together, they provide a special mechanism that allows tidyverse packages to construct [lambda functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function) on the fly. This is best described in [`?purrr::as_mapper`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/purrr/versions/0.2.5/topics/as_mapper). Specifically,

> If a formula, e.g. ~ .x + 2, it is converted to a function. There are three ways to refer to the arguments:
>
> - For a single argument function, use .
> - For a two argument function, use .x and .y
> - For more arguments, use ..1, ..2, ..3 etc

Using your example:

```
purrr::as_mapper( ~. > 5 )
# <lambda>
# function (..., .x = ..1, .y = ..2, . = ..1)
# . > 5
# attr(,"class")
# [1] "rlang_lambda_function"
```

creates a function that returns a logical value indicating whether the argument of the function is greater than 5. `purrr::detect()` [generates this function internally](https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/blob/43c3eb329001152762f618a62beec111702734b9/R/find-position.R#L38) and then uses it to traverse the input vector `x`. The final result is the first element of `x` that satisfies the "greater than 5" constraint.

As pointed out by Konrad, this mechanism is specific to tidyverse and does *not* work in general. Outside of tidyverse, the behavior of this syntax is explained in a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13446256/meaning-of-tilde-dot-argument).

Comment: +1. It’s worth highlighting that this mention does *not* work in general, it only works with specific functions (unlike anonymous functions, which work everywhere).