# Tilde and dots in R

Tags: r, function, dataframe, dplyr

I know this is more of a general basic question. But still it's kind of confusing to me. The "problems" are the `~` and the `.` in `R`. They just pop up everywhere and I don't know exactly what they mean in every context. There is for example this code, where I want to encode each -1 or -9 to be `NA`:

```
df_clean = dplyr::mutate_all(df, ~ifelse(. %in% c(-1, -9), NA, .))
```

So `df` in this case is a `data.frame` with several columns. Some of them containing many `NAs`. 
But why the `~` in front of the `ifelse`? 
And the first `.` helps to iterate over each row?

Sorry for the confusion. But maybe someone can explain this with some easy words;)

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/q/53159979/680068

Comment: Or when reading the data, define NAs: `myData <- read.table("myFile.txt", na.strings = c("-1", "-9"))`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `.` here refers to values in the column whereas `~` is a formula style syntax to represent the function. It is a style of coding than anything else.

This can also be represented using an anonymous function as in base R

```
dplyr::mutate_all(df, function(x) ifelse(x %in% c(-1, -9), NA, x))
```

which is same as using `lapply` in base R :

```
lapply(df, function(x) ifelse(x %in% c(-1, -9), NA, x))
```