# Is it possible to do the binary logarithm plus one (log2+1) in an entire dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, logarithm

This is my data:

```
dat <- mtcars
dat$Brands <- rownames(dat)
dat$Info <- rep("Info", length(rownames(mtcars)))
```

I have seen that there are a lot of ways to do something into an entire data frame. `mutate`, `sapply`, etc. However, for some particular functions it doesn't work.

The closest example is if you want to do `log2+1`.

I have tried this...

```
data_log <- dat %>% mutate(across(where(is.numeric), log2+1))
```

But it gives me this error...

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
> ℹ `..1 = across(where(is.numeric), log2 + 1)`.
> x non-numeric argument to binary operator
> Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Do you know if there is a way to run this type of function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your approach is correct but the syntax needs some correction. Here you need to use a lambda or an anonymous function.

Using `dplyr` you can use `across` as -

```
library(dplyr)
dat <- dat %>% mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~log2(.) +1))
```

Or in base R -

```
cols <- sapply(dat, is.numeric)
dat[cols] <- lapply(dat[cols], function(x) log2(x) + 1)
```

Comment: what does it mean the dot from `~log2(.)`? Thanks!

Comment: `.` is a placeholder for column value. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59855095/tilde-and-dots-in-r/ and the other related link for more info.

Comment: As of R 4.1.0 you can use the shorthand `dat[cols] <- lapply(dat[cols], \(x) log2(x)+1)`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table` methods.

```
library(data.table)
cols <- names(which(sapply(dat, is.numeric)))
setDT(dat)[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) log2(x) + 1), .SDcols = cols]
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually `log2` can be directly executed over a numerical data frame, so you can try the code below

```
idx <- sapply(dat, is.numeric)
dat[idx] <- log2(dat[idx])+1
```

Answer (score 0):

The above methods are good, but, can we not use log1p as described here:

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/log

It adds 1 to every element before computing log.

log1p(x) computes log(1+x),  accurately also for |x| <<1 (copied from above link).