# The function of tilde (~) in dplyr conditional select

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Let's say I have a raw dataset like below. As a tidying process, I tried selecting columns without NA values -or removing columns with NA-, referencing [this](https://www.statology.org/remove-columns-with-na-in-r/)

raw_data

```
 #>   data_name col_a  col_b
 #>   <chr>      <int> <int>
 #> 1 data_a     30    NA
 #> 2 data_b     20    75
 #> 3 sum        50    NA
```

code for dropping NA columns

```
data_without_na <- raw_data %>% select_if(~ !any(is.na(.)))
data_without_na
```

output

```
#>   data_name col_a
#>   <chr>      <int>
#> 1 data_a     30    
#> 2 data_b     20    
#> 3 sum        50
```

The output is as I wanted, but I'm confused why I need tilde (~) at the beginning of the condition.

Here's what I understand so far:

- tilde in R: separate the left hand side of an equation from the right hand side
- !: negation
- any(is.na(.)): true or false value for each column if there's any na value

How tilde works without left hand side variable?

Comment: This has been mugrated from DS to here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse) use of `~` is equivalent of `function(...)`. Basically, [`~` converts a formula-like expression to a function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/purrr/versions/0.2.5/topics/as_mapper). See below:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  select_if(function(x) !any(is.na(x)))
#>   data_name col_a
#> 1    data_a    30
#> 2    data_b    20
#> 3       sum    50

df %>% 
  select_if(~ !any(is.na(.)))
#>   data_name col_a
#> 1    data_a    30
#> 2    data_b    20
#> 3       sum    50
```

I can try and explain further but there are multiple threads on StackOverflow which explain this better, so I'd just refer to those:

1. [Tilde Dot in R (~.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53159979/tilde-dot-in-r)
2. [Meaning of tilde and dot notation in dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68249625/meaning-of-tilde-and-dot-notation-in-dplyr)

#### Data:

```
df <- read.table(text = " data_name col_a  col_b
 data_a     30    NA
 data_b     20    75
 sum        50    NA", header = T)
```