# Insert rows corresponding to each month in an yearly data

Tags: r, data-transform, data-handling

I have a dataframe with yearly data from 2014 to 2018. I wish to expand this dataframe into monthly values and basically divide each variable's value by 12 as each month's value.
**Please note**: There is no month column in my dataframe as of now.
So, if there are 5 products, I have 5*5 rows and 5 columns :"year", "Product_ID", "Var1", "Var2" and "Var3" as the columns.

Eventually, I want 5*12 rows and 6 column with "month" inserted as well.

I have tried this code but it isnt working:

```
df_new$date <- NA
df_new <- complete(df,Product_ID, date = full_seq(2014,1))
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use `uncount` to repeat rows 12 times, create a new column `month` to take `1:12` value for each `year` and then divide `Var` columns by 12.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  uncount(12) %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  mutate(month = 1:12) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(Var1, Var2), ~./12)

# Groups:   year [3]
#    year Product_ID  Var1  Var2 month
#   <int> <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <int>
# 1  2013 A          0.833     5     1
# 2  2013 A          0.833     5     2
# 3  2013 A          0.833     5     3
# 4  2013 A          0.833     5     4
# 5  2013 A          0.833     5     5
# 6  2013 A          0.833     5     6
# 7  2013 A          0.833     5     7
# 8  2013 A          0.833     5     8
# 9  2013 A          0.833     5     9
#10  2013 A          0.833     5    10
# … with 26 more rows
```

---

Or another option with `complete` and `fill`

```
df %>%
  mutate(month = 1) %>%
  complete(year, month = 1:12) %>%
  fill(Product_ID, Var1, Var2) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(Var1, Var2), ~./12)
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(year = 2013:2015, Product_ID = c("A", "B", "C"), 
      Var1 = c(10, 20, 30), Var2 = c(60, 80, 120), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Hey, I need a clarification. I understand "~." means divide each variable on the left handside with 12. But I am unable to understand the meaning of this symbol together. If I use only ´mutate_at(vars(Var1, Var2), /12)´ it is giving an error. I have read this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13446256/meaning-of-tilde-dot-argument and ?formula, etc, but this combination is still unclear to me. Can you explain its significance wrt this case?

Comment: @user10579790 those are `purrr` formula style functions , you can replace it with anonymous functions. Eg `mtcars %>% mutate_at(1, function(x) x + 10)` and `mtcars %>% mutate_at(1, ~. + 10)` are the same. They are just different coding styles. The link which you shared has a different reference and is not applicable here.