# What does it mean (.) in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

What does it mean (.) in R?
As in

```
sec_axis(~ log(2)/(.),
      breaks = c(2:7,14,21),
      name = "Doubling time (days)")
  )
```

Besides, it gives an error. The error message is
Error: transformation for secondary axes must be monotonic

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/13446256/680068 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/14976331/680068

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give out a proper answer, you should post a reproducible example: data + the ggplot code.

---

If `sec_axis()` is inside `scale_y_continuous`, the `.` is the place holder for the values shown on the main Y axis [if it's in `scale_x_continuous`, it's the place holder for the values shown on the main X axis.].

---

About the error, I wasn't able to reproduce it. You need to share your ggplot code (a minimal reproducible example that shows the error) and the version you have of `ggplot2`.

EDIT:

I managed to reproduce the error.

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x = 1:100, y = rnorm(100))

# works!
ggplot(df) +
    geom_line(aes(x = x, y = y))

# doesn't work
ggplot(df) +
    geom_line(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
    scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~1/.))
#> Errore: transformation for secondary axes must be monotonic
```

That happens because zero belongs to the Y axis. In R if you try to divide by zero, it will return Inf, which can't be plotted in an axis. Therefore, the error.

The only way to avoid it is a trick: change the labels and the breaks, without actually applying any transformation. As the example below (obviously this example is meaningless):

```
ggplot(df) +
    geom_line(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
    scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~., label = c(-10:-1, 1:10), breaks = 1/c(-10:-1, 1:10)))
```

[image]

In order to reproduce Professor Hyndman's chart, you should do as follow:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tsibble)
library(tidycovid19) #remotes::install_github("joachim-gassen/tidycovid19")

updates <- download_merged_data(cached = TRUE)

updates %>%
    mutate(
        cases_logratio = difference(log(confirmed))
    ) %>%
    filter(iso3c %in% countries) %>%
    filter(date >= as.Date("2020-03-01")) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = date, y = cases_logratio, col = country)) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = log(2)/c(2:7,14,21), col='grey') +
    geom_smooth(method = "loess", se = FALSE) +
    scale_y_continuous(
        "Daily increase in cumulative cases",
        breaks = log(1+seq(0,60,by=10)/100),
        labels = paste0(seq(0,60,by=10),"%"),
        minor_breaks=NULL,
        sec.axis = sec_axis(~ .,
                            labels = c(2:7,14,21),
                            breaks = log(2)/c(2:7,14,21),
                            name = "Doubling time (days)")
    ) +
    ggthemes::scale_color_colorblind()
```

[image]

Comment: You are right. The code is from Robert Hyndman's blog, https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/logratios-covid19/ . I am trying to reproduce the last figure; copying down his code gives me the aforementioned error and my guess is that it is at the reproduced line. Data ara loaded from the tidycovid19 package. The y variable in the graph is cases_logratio. Thanks!

Comment: okay, the example helped a lot. Check out my edit. I think I got what you were looking for.

Comment: If you think we reached the right solution, you should selected it, so that other users know and may find it more useful. Otherwise, let me know if there is any unclear part.