# Create a formula from (very) long list

Tags: r, function, variables, formula

I have a high-dimensional data frame `df` with dimensions of 3000 x 80 (a document term matrix). I have a classification function that takes in two arguments: `formula` and `data`. For `formula`, I want it to take all the features (variables) of `df` automatically. Is there a way to take in a list of all column names to create a formula object?

Comment: Formulas can use a `.` to refer to all variables: `~ . ` See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13446256/4996248)

Comment: True, but wildcards can only be used with implemented functions such as `lm` and others right? What if my function doesn't support this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could probably do

```
reformulate(names(df))
```

which will produce a one-sided formula with all of the variable names. (It's really not much more than syntactic sugar for `as.formula(paste(names(df), collapse="+"))`.)

Answer (score -1):

For a formula use:

```
as.formula(paste( "dependent_var ~ ", paste(names(df), collapse="+"))
```